# Silence errors and warnings in PHP using @ and the getCollectionNames() function

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using the `PHP` driver `v1.4.1` and calling:

```
$collections = @$db->getCollectionNames()
```

I want to intentionally **force silence** any errors, thus why I am using `@` before the function call. However, this does not silence errors. I still receive PHP errors thrown about (*No candidate servers found*) when I change a MongoDB primary or take all MongoDB nodes down.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a bad idea to suppress the errors like this, I think, you should follow the errors and solve those from the root.

Comment: What you are probably seeing is an exception rather then an error.. try putting the code in a try / catch block to confirm. Also you should respond to exceptions/errors instead of supressing them.

Comment: Did you try using `ini_set('display_errors', 0)` ?

Comment: You can set a default error handler function for all errors.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

The fix was putting a `try/catch` around the call.

```
try {
    $collections = @$db->getCollectionNames();
} catch(Exception $mongoException) {
    //some logic here
}
```